# What are the prerequisites for regression analysis?

Tags: regression-analysis

I want to be able to read this book:
[Data Analysis using Multilevel and Hierarchal models?](http://www.stat.columbia.edu/~gelman/arm/)

I have read "[Think Stats](http://greenteapress.com/thinkstats/)" published by O'Reilly and have taken some higher math classes in algebra and analysis. Not a lot of probability and statistics experience though.

What books would I have to read as prerequisites? Or should I just go ahead and buy it?

Comment: Most texts have a forward where they describe the prerequisites.

Comment: I don't know if I can see that without already buying the book.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the preface, which you can see by checking [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/052168689X)'s "look inside" feature.  Here's what it says:

> "The prerequisite is statistics up to and including an introduction to multiple regression.  Advanced mathematics is not assumed - it is important to understand the linear model in regression, but it is not necessary to follow the matrix algebra in the derivation of least squares computations.  It is useful to be familiar with exponents and logarithms, especially when working with generalized linear models."